# Neo4j Account Restriction and Multiple Databases

Tags: neo4j

I know that we can get access to Neo4j db remotely by adding IP addresses. I am wondering if Neo4j supports account verification like username and password to double increase the db security even though we log in at trusted IP.

In addition, can we set mulitple databases and switch them before we query some stuff? I know Neo4jCP can do it but it only supports windows. Is there any way else to do it and is it possible that Neo4j intergrates this feature?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately out of the box Neo4j doesn't support multiple databases or user management or data level security.

You can add something like that in your application layer, or use a framework like http://structr.org which provides user-management and data level security.